# What is the HTML Interaction Tag

Tags: html, embedding

I have seen some embed codes provided as `<interaction>` tag. For instance, [Apester](http://apester.com/)'s so-called HTML5 embed code goes like this

```
<interaction id="57b6f819336e03ca34e0fb8b"></interaction>
```

I have seen this with other providers of embed codes before (well at least once), but I can't find anything on this tag, not at W3C, WHATWG or MDN. I am wondering, what is this, how does it work and where can I read about it?

Comment: Maybe it's custom tag that has no purpose in HTML5? You can name tag `<mytag></mytag>` and use it later in code for easier access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not standard, but a custom tag from Apester. Their javascript library (or sdk) will see it and use it. For more info, see [this](http://help.apester.com/hc/en-us/articles/205649881-Smart-Content-Recommendation-SDK-Documentation) link.